# My camera and movement breaks when I use a morph

Tags: roblox

Basically, I have this morph in my game that lets me turn into a dog, but when I use it, my camera doesn't go to where my player teleported to after transforming, and I'm not able to move.

```
local pad = script.Parent
local characterName = "Sammy"
local character = pad.Parent:WaitForChild(characterName)

local debounce = true
pad.Touched:Connect(function(obj)
    local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(obj.Parent)
    if plr and debounce == true then
        debounce = false

        local charClone = character:Clone()
        charClone.Name = plr.Name
        plr.Character = charClone
        
        local rootPart = charClone:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart") or charClone:FindFirstChild("Torso")
        local plrRoot = obj.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart") or obj.Parent:FindFirstChild("Torso")

        if rootPart and plrRoot then
            rootPart.CFrame = plrRoot.CFrame
        end

        charClone.Parent = workspace

        wait(.5)

        debounce = true
        
    end
end)
```

Comment: Found out the problem! For anyone else having the same problem, it might be because your animate script requires your rig to have a humanoid. Although if your rig isn't an average R6 or R15 Rig, you wont be able to put a humanoid in it. You'll need to make your own animation script that doesn't require a humanoid.